# Disable load scripts and styles not working

Tags: scripts, css

I'm trying to disable the load of  nextgen gallery 2.x styles and scripts, I used

```
function mytheme_deregister_scripts_and_styles(){
  $unwanted_scripts = array(
    'photocrati_ajax'
  );
  foreach ( $unwanted_scripts as $script ) {
    wp_dequeue_script( $script );
    wp_deregister_script( $script );
  }

  $unwanted_styles = array(
    'photocrati-nextgen_basic_compact_album'
  );
  foreach ( $unwanted_styles as $style ) {
    wp_dequeue_style( $style );
    wp_deregister_style( $style );
  }
    // to display their handles
/*  global $wp_scripts;
    echo '<div style="position:absolute; left:200px; top:200px; background:white; z-index:100;">';
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) :
        echo "<p>";
        echo $handle;
        echo "</p>";
    endforeach; 
    echo "</div>"; */ 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_deregister_scripts_and_styles', 99 );
**SCRIPTS AND STYLES LIST:**
```

However, nothing changed the styles are still being loaded. What is wrong with the code, and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you verified those scripts and styles are hooked onto `wp_print_styles`?  I'd bet they're actually hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: They are actually plugins stuff, I had to print them out so I can get their handle name to skip them, but the code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function mytheme_deregister_scripts_and_styles(){
  $unwanted_scripts = array(
    'photocrati_ajax',
    'photocrati-nextgen_basic_thumbnails',
    'photocrati-nextgen_basic_extended_album'
  );
  foreach ( $unwanted as $script ) {
    wp_dequeue_script( $script );
    wp_deregister_script( $script );
  }

  $unwanted_styles = array(
    'style_1',
    'style_2'
  );
  foreach ( $unwanted_styles as $style ) {
    wp_dequeue_style( $style );
    wp_deregister_style( $style );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_deregister_scripts_and_styles', 99 );
```

It looks like you may not have it quite right:

```
wp_deregister_script('photocrati_ajax');
wp_deregister_style('photocrati-nextgen_basic_compact_album');
wp_dequeue_style( 'photocrati-nextgen_basic_compact_album' );
```

If they have already been registered and enqueued, I'd make sure to both deregister and dequeue them.

Also, make sure to use the _script commands on the scripts and the _style commands on the styles.

**If they are not using wp_enqueue_styles...**

You can remove items added via other actions and filters by using the remove_filter and remove_action items after they are called but before they are fired. (if the add_actions are placed on init, then you could put your actions to remove them later on the init hook)

**If they manually draw them into the plugin**
Then that is just bad design ... and you will likely have to edit their plugin and just comment out the place they add them at.

Comment: I tried your code after fixing $wanted variable in the first foreach, however it didn't skip any style or script!

Comment: Have you checked to see what hook they are using to enqueue scripts? Standard practice is to use the wp_enqueue_scripts hook ... but if they are doing their on a later hook that could well be the problem. Some plugins even simply write out their script and css links using the wp_head action. If the above doesn't work maybe they are doing something odd.

Comment: How can I know how are they hooked in the plugins! nextgen styles are loaded in the header section, while its scripts are loaded in the footer section

Comment: Use a good text editor and do a directory wide search for those values in the plugin directory in question. That should show how they are being added. e.g. search for photocrati_ajax or photocrati-nextgen_basic

Comment: The code is fine, the problem is not all styles are hooked using wp_enqueue, is there other way to skip these styles?

Comment: Updated the answer to address plugins not using wp_enqueue_scripts.